# Reading the equality $\left \| w+d(x)x \right \|^{2}=w^2+2d(x)w\cdot x+x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm somewhat confused since I don't quite understand the meaning of the equality $\left \| w+d(x)x \right \|^{2}=w^2+2d(x)w\cdot x+x^2$. Here,  $\left \| \right \|$ denotes the length of the vector, $w$ and $x$ are vectors, $d(x)$ takes vector as an argument and evaluates to either $1$ or $-1$ and "$\cdot$" is inner product. What does $w^2$ or $x^2$ mean? Maybe it should be $\left \| w \right \|^2$ and $\left \| x \right \|^2$ respectively?

Comment: I would imagine $w^2$ means do the dot product of $w$ with itself since if you expand the norm on the left hand side then that is the expression you will get.

Comment: This is of course the same as $\|w\|^2$, i.e. $w \cdot w=\|w\|^2$.

Comment: Let's say $x^2$ means $\|x\|^2$. Then, you have $\|w+d(x)x\|^2 = w^2+d(x)^2x^2+2d(x)\cdot x$. Where did $d(x)^2$ go ?

Comment: oh, didn't mention, $d(x)$ always evaluates to either $1$ or $-1$, sorry

Comment: made a corresponding edit. @Dean, your answer seems to be correct, post it as an answer so I can select it as a correct one :)

Comment: If you are looking for a "meaning", then think of it as simply the law of cosines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x \rangle=x \cdot x$. Therefore since $d(x)$ evaluates to a scalar
$$\|w+d(x)x\|^2=\langle w+d(x)x,w+d(x)x \rangle = \langle w,w \rangle + 2\langle w,d(x)x \rangle + \langle d(x)x,d(x)x\rangle = w \cdot w +2d(x) x \cdot w + x \cdot x$$
using the assumption that you have just given me that says $d(x)$ always squares to be 1, (admittedly I missed that when I wrote the comment!)